# Question about accessing indices in nested lists

Tags: python, list

I was learning about Deep Learning in Kaggle through an exercise and this confused me. In order to write a code for checking whether something was a hot dog or not, there was a list of predictions, with each element being the most likely prediction for what a different image was. So the overall list was :

```
[
    [('n07697537', 'hotdog', 0.8770528)], 
    [('n07697537', 'hotdog', 0.9659182)], 
    [('n07579787', 'plate', 0.7972369)], 
    [('n07583066', 'guacamole', 0.9996675)]
]
```

And one element is:

```
[('n07697537', 'hotdog', 0.9659182)]
```

So in order to check whether an image is most likely a hotdog, I'd have to get that second field, the label. But I ran into some syntax issues trying to access the field inside the nested list.

So I tried accessing the first element's label as an example (decoded is the name of the outer list) with `print(decoded[0][1])`. This didn't work. So I checked the sample solution after failing to figure out how to access the element cleanly without having to do something convoluted.
The sample code used

```
labels = [d[0][1] for d in decoded]
```

And that successfully makes a list of the labels. I tried to do something similar before checking the solution but I was slightly off, I tried the singular version of this by setting `d = decoded[0]` , and I got a list of length 1 with the three elements, like the element example earlier. What I found confusing is that `d[0][1]` works to give the me label, but `decoded[0][1]` does not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on tuples :

```
decoded = [[('n07697537', 'hotdog', 0.8770528)], [('n07697537', 'hotdog', 0.9659182)], [('n07579787', 'plate', 0.7972369)], [('n07583066', 'guacamole', 0.9996675)]]
d = [x for y in decoded for x in y]
labels = [d[0][1] for d in decoded]
```

This script gives:

```
['hotdog', 'hotdog', 'plate', 'guacamole']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access the first element's label aka 'hotdog' in the first tuple, you need to `print(decoded[0][0][1])` where the `[1]` in `decoded[0][0][1]` is the 2nd element in the tuple (0-indexed), the right hand `[0]` is the tuple itself, and the left hand `[0]` is the inner list.

Some background: there is actually a list enclosing other lists of tuples in your example shown as `[[()],[()],[()]]` where `()` is a tuple and `[]` is a list. You could in theory have multiple tuples in each inner list like `[[(),(),()],[(),()],[()]]` etc. However, you access values within tuples the same way as you do with lists, using indices, hence the confusion.

The code `[d[0][1] for d in decoded]` works because `d` is actually just a list of tuples (though only one tuple is in the list in this case).

Comment: Great explanation! I'm new to Python so I didn't really understand tuples, thanks for clearing that up.